# Why does different parameters for umask result in the same file permissions?

Tags: command-line, unix, file-permissions, umask

I tried changing [umask](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) settings for some files as:

`umask 0012` for file c:

`-rw-rw-r-- 1 unipro unipro     0 2010-10-15 11:30 c`

`umask 0013` for file d:

`-rw-rw-r-- 1 unipro unipro     0 2010-10-15 11:32 d`

How is it that both have the same permissions, even after using different umask permissions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask):

```
The umask only restricts permissions; it cannot grant extra
permissions beyond what is specified by the program that
creates the file or directory.
```

Real file permissions are calculated in this way:

```
real-permissions = requested-permissions AND NOT( umask )
```

`requested-permissions` is usually `0666` for files (and `0777` for directories), so:

```
0666 AND NOT( 0012 ) = 0664
0666 AND NOT( 0013 ) = 0664
```

Answer (score 1):

Well 1 is execute, and `umask` can't add permissions, so I'm guessing neither of these files had +x set to begin with?